# Calculus Review - Differentiating an Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I'm trying to review some calculus over the summer and I just wanted to double-check my answer to a simple problem I came up with myself. Thanks.

> What is: $\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^{g(x)} f(t)\;dt\;$?

Using the chain rule,  I got $\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^{g(x)} f(t)\;dt = \frac{d}{dx} (F(g(x)) = f(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$.

Comment: You answer is ok.

Comment: You have done right. Do you want a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want you can take a simple example (just to see the things are proper):

$\large\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x} e^{t} dt = \frac{d}{dx}\big(e^{x}-1)= e^{x} $

And as per the formula,

$\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^{g(x)} f(t)\;dt = \frac{d}{dx} (F(g(x)) = f(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$

You will get,

$e^{(x)}\cdot 1 = e^{x}$